# One observation per level in mixed-effect model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, mixed-model

Field explains how to analyse repeated-measures data using linear mixed-effect models (LME). See Field et al., Discovering Statistics Using R, 2012, p. 573.

However, the way he specifies the model, there appears to be **only one observation per level of the grouping factors**. Is this a mistake in the textbook? If not, why not? It seems to me the random effects specify a full model and fit the data (almost) exactly.

The code is as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(nlme)
# Load dataset:
dat.wide <- read.delim("http://www.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20Data%20Files/Chapter%2013/Bushtucker.dat")

dat.wide
#   participant stick_insect kangaroo_testicle fish_eye witchetty_grub
# 1          P1            8                 7        1              6
# 2          P2            9                 5        2              5
# 3          P3            6                 2        3              8
# 4          P4            5                 3        1              9
# 5          P5            8                 4        5              8
# 6          P6            7                 5        6              7
# 7          P7           10                 2        7              2
# 8          P8           12                 6        8              1


dat <- melt(dat.wide, variable.name="animal", value.name="retch")
head(dat)
#   participant       animal retch
# 1          P1 stick_insect     8
# 2          P2 stick_insect     9
# ...

# set contrasts, not relevant to question but keeps example same as in book:
PartvsWhole <- c(1, -1, -1, 1)
TesticlevsEye <- c(0, -1, 1, 0)
StickvsGrub <- c(-1, 0, 0, 1)
contrasts(dat$animal) <- cbind(PartvsWhole, TesticlevsEye, StickvsGrub)

# Fit intercept term, then add "animal" term.
# NOTE: random effects are animal nested within participant, as in textbook.
# This would presumably give one observation per group?    
lme1 <- lme(retch ~ 1, random=~1|participant/animal, data=dat, method="ML")
lme2 <- lme(retch ~ 1 + animal, random=~1|participant/animal, data=dat, method="ML")

# I have checked these are the same results as in textbook
anova(lme1, lme2)    
summary(lme2)

# residuals are near-zero (e-05)
resid(lme2)

ran1 <- random.effects(lme1)
ran2 <- random.effects(lme2)
# same number of random effects as observations:
nrow(ran1$animal)
    nrow(ran2$animal)
nrow(dat)
```

The concern of one observation per level seems to be confirmed by using package lme4 instead:

```
library(lme4)
# Using lme4 produces an error:
# "Error in checkNlevels(reTrms$flist, n = n, control) : 
# number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations"    
lmer1 <- lmer(retch ~ 1 + (1|participant/animal), data=dat, REML=F)
lmer2 <- lmer(retch ~ 1 + animal + (1|participant/animal), data=dat, REML=F)
anova(lmer1, lmer2)

# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713228/lmer-returning-error-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-observations
# can force fit with lme4:
# control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",
#                     check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore",
#                     check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))

lmer1 <- lmer(retch ~ 1 + (1|participant/animal), data=dat, REML=F,
              control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore",
                                  check.nobs.vs.rankZ="ignore",
                                  check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
lmer2 <- lmer(retch ~ 1 + animal + (1|participant/animal), data=dat, REML=F,
              control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore",
                                  check.nobs.vs.rankZ="ignore",
                                  check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
# ignoring errors, we get the same results as with lme:
anova(lmer1, lmer2)
anova(lme1, lme2) # same
```

Should the random term should be 1|participant instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly seems that `animal` nested within `participant` is confounded with the residual variance, although it would help to see a relevant descriptive excerpt from the book (those pages aren't available on Google Books).

```
with(dat,table(participant,animal))
```

shows the lack of replication that you refer to.

Another hint that something is wrong with the model:

```
intervals(lme1)
## Error in intervals.lme(lme1) : 
  cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: 
  Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance
```

It's also worth pointing out (I don't know if the authors do) that the estimated among-participant variance is zero, which could be due to a lack of replication or to a negative correlation within individuals (e.g. someone who likes grubs less than average would like stick insects more than average); this could in principle be handled by a compound symmetry correlation structure with a negative correlation.

I've posted [a similar example](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/uqam/mixedlab1.pdf).